# How to set up a PowerShell command in Windows Task Scheduler with administrative privileges?

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, elevated-privileges

I am currently trying to run the command `cup all -y` with task scheduler in windows, which basically updates all the packages installed by Chocolatey package installer.

[Screenshot of PowerShell ISE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKkdS.png)

I have scheduled the task to run whenever I login to the computer, PowerShell window pops up for a brief second and goes away, and then nothing happens.

I am not sure if the command is being executed and the packages are getting updated.

Kindly help me with this.

I have tried to change the path to system32 to make it run with administrative privileges using the following command:

`Set-Location -Path C:\Windows\system32`

Also tried clicking on "Run with highest privileges" in task scheduler while creating a task, that didn't work as well.

Comment: As an aside: Using `Set-Location` to change the current location to `C:\Windows\system32` is unrelated to whether or not your scheduled task runs with administrative privileges.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run as scheduled task as yourself, interactively, but *with elevation* (administrative privileges), define the user context with [`New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskprincipal) with `-RunLevel Highest` as follows, to be passed to [`Register-ScheduledTask`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/register-scheduledtask)'s `-Principal` parameter later:

```bash
# NOTE: Setting up a scheduled task this way requires
#       running from an ELEVATED session too.
# -LogonType Interactive  is implied.
# Pass the result to Register-ScheduledTask -Principal. 
New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -RunLevel Highest -UserID $env:USERNAME
```

Note:

- This assumes that your user account is an administrator account.
- For troubleshooting, you can place a `pause` statement at the end of your script, so you'll see what happens during execution of the script as a scheduled task.
  Alternatively, invoke the script with the `-NoExit` PowerShell CLI parameter, which keeps the PowerShell session alive after executing the script, but for security reasons you should only do that during troubleshooting.

---

Here's a **complete example**, which sets up a task to run interactively, with elevation, whenever you log on.

It uses a sample PowerShell command that simply displays a message and waits for the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to close the window again. Replace
`-Command "'Hi from the scheduled task running with elevation'; pause"` with something like
`-File C:\path\to\your\Script.ps1`

```bash
#requires -RunAsAdministrator
    
# == The command (program) to run.
$action = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute powershell -Argument @'
-NoProfile -Command "'Hi from the scheduled task running with elevation'; pause"
'@
  
# == Run as yourself, interactively, with elevation.
$user = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserID $env:USERNAME -RunLevel Highest 

# == Run on your every logon
$trigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -AtLogOn -User $env:USERNAME

# == Register the task with name '_Test'
New-ScheduledTask -Action $action -Principal $user -Trigger $trigger | 
  Register-ScheduledTask '_Test' -Force

# Command to later remove the task again:
# Unregister-ScheduledTask -ErrorAction Ignore -TaskName _Test -Confirm:$false
```