# How to create Scheduled Task Powershell script, which restarts IIS?

Tags: powershell, iis

I'm trying to create powershell script for Scheduled task which restarts my IIS server, but I cannot find how to sed the command "iisreset" in the task action.

If I run only "iisreset" in the powershell, it works, but I want to be part of Scheduled task.

Here is my code:

```
# task name
$taskName = "RestartIIS"

# create trigger
$taskTrigger = New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -Weekly -At 6:33pm -DaysOfWeek Thursday

# create action for restarting
$taskAction = New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "iisreset"

# check if this task already exists
$existingTask = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($existingTask -ne $null) {
    Write-Host "WARNING! Task with name '$taskName' already exists. If you choose to delete the old one, the new one will be created!" -ForegroundColor Yellow
    Unregister-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}

Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $taskName -Action $taskAction -Trigger $taskTrigger
Write-Host "Task $taskName registered and set for every Sunday at 1:00am!" -ForegroundColor Green
```

Thanks.

I googled it but it was no result, I checked the Microsoft docs, but it doesn't help me too.

Comment: Just a terrible idea to run that tool frequently. What is the issue you want to hide on this machine? Faulty web apps should be fixed themselves, not forcing IIS to restart.

Comment: It's my first Powershell script. My teamlead ask me to write PS script for cronjob which restart IIS every week. After research I created this, but I am open for other decisions.

Comment: You can try the solution mentioned by Cpt.Whale, I think it can work for you. Just refer to official doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/scheduledtasks/new-scheduledtaskaction?view=windowsserver2022-ps#-execute

Comment: This answer was helped me to resolve the problem:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75966484/14596343

Comment: I'm glad that your problem has been solved. If possible, you can post the solution as an answer, and mark your answer as an accepted answer after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Answer (score 1):

`-Execute` refers to an executable file instead of a command. To run IISRESET in powershell, you would want something closer to

```
New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute 'Powershell.exe' -Argument '-C iisreset'
```